# SpringApplication.run runs all CommandLineRunner beans

Tags: spring-boot

I have a single project which contains multiple `main` classes. Here's one (simplified):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ModelStaging implements CommandLineRunner
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(ModelStaging.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception
    {
        /* lots of code omitted */
    }
}
```

What I'm finding is, running any one of them triggers the `run` method of ALL of them!

Also unexpected: my project also contains a class for launching RESTful services. Launching the services also calls every `run` method of every `SpringBootApplication` class.

(Note that something similar happens in reverse: when I run any of the command line utilities, the RESTful service beans are also discovered and the service starts running. This one at least I understand and should have seen coming!)

Is this expected behavior? Is it documented anywhere? What is the purpose of the class argument to `SpringApplication.run` if not to control whose `run` method gets called?

Naturally I can restructure the packages and/or the component scan so that the various `SpringBootApplication` classes don't discover each other (and don't discover the RESTful service beans when they shouldn't) but I'd like to understand this better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does mean the `SpringBootApplication` annotation ?  (emphasis is mine)

> Indicates a configuration class that declares one or more @Bean
>   methods and also triggers auto-configuration and component scanning.
>   **This is a convenience annotation that is equivalent to declaring
>   @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan**.

So annotating multiples classes with it will by consequence instantiate multiple configuration/bean instances.

And what is the role of the `CommandLineRunner` interface ? (emphasis is mine)

> Interface used to indicate that **a bean should run when it is contained
>   within a SpringApplication**. Multiple CommandLineRunner beans can be
>   defined within the same application context and can be ordered using
>   the Ordered interface or @Order annotation.

So the actual noticed behavior is which one expected.
Whatever the way which you run your application, all SpringBootApplication beans are instantiated and also you don't need to invoke explicitly `run()` to make them run.

To achieve what you want (exclude some beans and include some others), using Spring Boot profiles could be a way.

Comment: Good explanation, thanks. Still curious why a class is passed to the run method- to the untutored eye it looks like that is the class that will be run.

Comment: You are very welcome. The class is passed because it is the classic way to run a Spring Boot application. So that is unavoidable.

Comment: Incidentally your suggestion about using Spring Boot profiles was spot on. I annotated a few classes and that was it. Even better: by selecting the active profile in each main() method (by calling SpringApplication.setAdditionalProfiles) I get exactly the effect I originally wanted: the caller just executes a particular main() class, and everything works. The caller doesn't need to know about the profiles at all.

Answer (score 1):

`SpringApplication.run` and `CommandLineRunner.run` have no relation at all to each other, they just happen to have the same name. The documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner mentions having multiple implementations of that interface, so it can be inferred from there, that all implementations would be executed.

Additionally, the classname in your example in `SpringApplication.run(Model.class, args)` simply tells Spring, in which class to look for the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

It is also no requirement to have the main method in the same class where CommandLineRunner is implemented.

Comment: The other answer was first and covered a little more ground, but i appreciated having a second, different explanation. Thanks!